# addEventListener doesn't work on element created by createElement

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
const append = ({ el, children }) => {
  const child = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(children);
  el.appendChild(child);
};

const element = function (elType, children, options = {}) {
  const el = document.createElement(elType);

  const { onClick } = options;

  if (onClick) {
    console.log(el, "el");
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      onClick(e);
    });
  }

  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    children.map((child) => {
      append({ el, children: child });
    });
  } else {
    append({ el, children });
  }

  return el.outerHTML;
};

export default element;
```

Above you can see my `element` function , which I will use for creating my element with some type, for my case I interested in button element , I want to start listen on click event on button element , check my code belowe

```
 element("div", [
    element("button", "Home page", {
      onClick: () => console.log("click"),
    }),
    children,
  ]);
```

But when I click to my button , it doesn't work , what can be the reason ?

Comment: Maybe you should returno the el itself instead of its outerHtml

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: when I return el itself , I get [object HTMLDivElement] in dom

Comment: Because you're trying to insert it into a string, instead of appending it to the DOM

Comment: Here's my version: https://jsfiddle.net/vs7r2hzj/

Comment: document.getElementById("root").innerHTML =myFunc() here is how I try to make it , I want to attach it to root )

Comment: yes, reason was that I was attaching it to innerHtml

Comment: Just do `document.getElementById("root").append(element(...));` instead. You were turning the created elements into a DOMString, losing the events in the process.

Comment: yes, you are right @ChrisG

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

> The outerHTML attribute of the Element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants

therefore returns HTML representing the element, but it's not the element.

Instead you should return `el` and use something like `appendChild`:

```
const element = function (elType, children, options = {}) {
  ...
  return el;
};

document.querySelector('...')(
  element("div", [
    element("button", "Home page", {
      onClick: () => console.log("click"),
    }),
    children,
  ])
)
```